# Nextjs - Can't read prop from Link Component address

Tags: next.js

I have a link component that looks like this:

```
'<Link href={`/product/${id.id}`}>'
```

The URL after clicking the above link looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/product/15b96476-c9c0-4ca2-86f0-32790da6c89f
```

When I click on the link I'd like to retrieve the id from the page

```
const page = ({id}) => {
//console.log
}
```

But when I try to console.log the id value it returns undefined. How do I access this value?

Comment: You can get an idea from next docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys so after a bit of Google-ing this has worked:

```
'use client'
import React from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'next/navigation';

    const page = () => {
       
      const {productid} = useParams();
    
      console.log(`${productid}`)
      return (
        <div>
      {productid}
       
        </div>
      )
    }

export default page
```